# Get input on same line as text in command line application

Tags: java

How do I get the input on the same line as my command line in a Java application:

I currently have

```
private static String input(String msg) {
    Log.log(Level.INFO, "" + msg + ": ");
    return null;
}

public void listen() {
    while (true) {
        // Display input message
        input("\ntest-cli");

        // Gather user input
        String rawInput = scanner.nextLine();

        // Check if the users wishes to quit
        if (rawInput.equals("quit") || rawInput.equals("exit")) {
            break;
        }

        // Gather the raw arguments entered by the user
        String[] rawArgs = rawInput.split("\\s+");

        // Check any command or argument was entered
        if (!rawArgs[0].equals("")) {

            /* Check if debug mode is false, if so then run command in try catch to avoid crashing the application
            if an error is thrown. Otherwise run the command with no safety net */

            if (!debugMode) {
                try {
                    call(rawArgs);
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    print("Command couldn't execute, perhaps not enough arguments? Try: " + rawArgs[0] + " help");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    print("Command failed to execute.");
                }
            } else {
                call(rawArgs);
            }
        }
    }
}

static void print(String msg) {
    Log.log(Level.INFO, msg);
}
```

which outputs:

```
test-cli: 
help
```

How do I get it to look like this (`rawInput` same line as `input`)

```
test-cli> help
```

Comment: You forgot to show us the `print` method. And the code you show does not produce the given result, I don't see any print for *"test-cli"* nor "*help*". Please create a [mcve].

Comment: `print` method added

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a logging library instead of just printing to standard out?

Comment: Its just used in general all over the application

Comment: You shouldn't really be using the log for input prompts.  In `input`, use Use `System.out.print(""+msg+"> "); System.out.flush();`